# Attaching WatiN to Firefox

Tags: c#, firefox, watin

Using WatiN, Im facing some issues with

`FireFox FF = new FireFox ("http://www.google.com");`,

FireFox always crashes at this point and VS report :

> Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed by the remote host

any idea why this is happening ?

Win7 32Bit - VS2008 - .NET 3.5 - Firefox 3.5 - WatiN-2.0.10.928-net-2.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The jssh that comes with Watin CTP has an issue with FireFox 3.5.

I downloaded [Swat](http://ulti-swat.wikispaces.com/) (Simple Web Automation Toolkit - sourceforge project) and it came with a newer version of jssh which is for FF 3.5 and now Watin starts FF successfully..

Comment: I'm running FireFox 3.6, and I ran into this same problem. Following the suggested solution, using jssh-Firefox36-WINNT.xpi found inside the SWAT download (http://sourceforge.net/projects/ulti-swat/) solved it for me.

Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Nailuj, what do we need to do with the .xpi file to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't WatiN use COM Interop under the covers?  You probably need to run your process as a 32 bit process (i.e. kick off 32 bit NUnit).